# Confidence intervals for a transformed

Tags: confidence-interval, data-transformation

We are trying to calculate a CI around an inverse proportion.
The sample is women who have had one caesarean section in the past and are now having a normal (vaginal) birth of another baby
The binomial outcome is a ruptured uterus during the second birth (yes/no)
The observed proportion is 0.5% (78 ruptures of sample size 15587)
Using SE = sqrt(p(1-p)/n) we get 95%CI = p +/- 1.96*SE = 0.39% to 0.61%
We wish to express the proportion as its inverse (as this may be easier for patients to understand) and the CI around that and have used:
point estimate = 1 in 200 (1/0.5%)
95% CI = 1 in 164 to 1 in 257 (inverting the limits of the 95%CI for proportions)
We thought this would be valid as the inverse is a monotonic function of the proportion

Then we started doubting this approach illustrated by the following example:
Imagine a random sample of peoples' heights from a large population which showed a mean height of 1.70cm and 95%CI 1.60cm to 1.80cm
Then imagine we wish to report on a transformed variable height-squared (silly but couldn't think of a better example).
Using the above approach we get mean height-squared = 1.7^2 = 2.89 with 95%CI 2.56 to 3.24 and thus the CI is not symmetrical about the point estimate.
We could alternatively 'measure' height-squareds' directly and we would get the same mean of 2.89 but the 95%CI would be symmetrical about this point estimate (+/- 1.96xSE)

Given 2 different 95%CIs, which of these 2 approaches would be incorrect? (or with a big enough sample would they give similar results?)

Answer (score 3):

You're correct that the CI you get by transforming the endpoints is not symmetric about the point estimate, but there's no reason to expect it to be; CIs are in general *not* symmetric (at least not in the sense that the endpoints of the interval are equidistant from the usual point estimate).

You're used to using a normal approximation to produce a CI for a proportion, which does produce a symmetric interval, but many methods for producing a binomial proportion confidence intervals produce endpoints that are not equidistant from the ordinary sample proportion.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval

Which is to say, you shouldn't necessarily think an interval for the proportion ought to be symmetric to start with.

Indeed insisting on that kind of symmetry in confidence intervals will in some situations - including with binomial proportions - do things you won't like, such as having your interval include impossible values for the parameter.

Even when you do have that kind of symmetry in an interval for a parameter, you shouldn't expect it when you consider an interval for a monotonic transformation of that parameter.

So for example, when you considered an interval for $\mu^2$ in the height example, you got an interval that was not symmetric about the estimate of $\mu^2$ you used. There's no reason to expect it to be symmetric. That example offers no basis to reject the asymmetric interval for the inverse of a proportion.

> We could alternatively 'measure' height-squareds' directly and we would get the same mean of 2.89

Well, no, we would not. The mean of the squares is larger than the square of the mean (unless the variance is 0, which won't be the case for real height data).

> but the 95%CI would be symmetrical about this point estimate (+/- 1.96xSE)

Why does it necessarily make sense that the interval for squared-height should be symmetric? It will be if you assume it's normal, but it cannot be the case that both height and height squared are actually normal. In fact neither can be normal since both are necessarily non-negative, but the distribution of height is less skewed than that of height-squared, and a normal-based interval for the population mean height will work reasonably well at somewhat smaller sample sizes than it would for the mean of its square.

A suitable *small-sample* interval for height-squared would perhaps be better based on a non-normal model for the population distribution. It might or might not be the case that some interval for the mean was symmetric, depending on how you generated the interval. I'd probably be inclined to use something like a shifted Weibull model (or possibly a shifted gamma) as a decent approximation to the distribution of squared heights, though other approaches could be used.

If the sample was not small, the interval for the mean of a moderately skew variable like the square of height based on a normal model would work reasonably well, nonetheless.

[1]: Incidentally, there's some reason to consider whether $\hat{\mu}^2$ (which you seem to be thinking of using to estimate $\mu^2$) is necessarily the point estimate you want to use to estimate $\mu^2$. That is, should $\widehat{\mu^2}=(\hat{\mu})^2$, necessarily? A good answer to that will depend on the properties you want for your estimator. If you wanted unbaisedness, you might not choose that one $-$ not that I am suggesting that you need to use unbiased estimators at all. On the other hand, if you like MLEs, then such direct transformation will be appropriate, as long as you started with an MLE, but then you should definitely *not* expect intervals to be symmetric about the point estimate.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer which was very useful, especially pointing out the difference between the mean if the squares and the square of the mean which now you have pointed it out are clearly different.